# Swift. Результат выводится с задержкой при парсинге JSON

Tags: json, swift

Есть код c парсингом JSON

```
    let url=URL(string:"http://........................")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {(data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }
        else
        {
                do
                {
                    let infoJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                    if let jsonData = infoJson["data"] as? NSDictionary
                    {
                            self.lblAddress.text=jsonData["address"]! as? String
                            self.lblSobstvennik.text=jsonData["consumername"]! as? String

                    } else {

                    }
                }
                catch let error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

Работает верно, данные возвращает.
Но lblAddress и lblSobstvennik заполняются с большой задержкой, около 10 секунд.
Если этот url выполнить в браузере, то данные вернет мгновенно.
Из-за чего так происходит?

Comment: А в главном ли потоке работает запись данных?

Comment: Как это узнать? Я новичок в Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я бы на вашем месте еще добавил в блок: **[unowned self]**, не хорошо в блок захватывать **self**. Может быть **Strong Reference Cycles**, вот [дока](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID56)

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { [unowned self] in
      self.lblAddress.text=jsonData["address"]! as? String
      self.lblSobstvennik.text=jsonData["consumername"]! as? String
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Исправил. Поместил запись данных в главный поток DispatchQueue.main.async...

```
let url=URL(string:"http://........................")
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {(data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
    }
    else
    {
            do
            {
                let infoJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                if let jsonData = infoJson["data"] as? NSDictionary
                {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        self.lblAddress.text=jsonData["address"]! as? String
                        self.lblSobstvennik.text=jsonData["consumername"]! as? String
                    })

                } else {

                }
            }
            catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
    }
}
task.resume()
```